# よね and じゃん: めっちゃ褒めてくれるじゃん

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Going off of my last question, I put some thought into the difference between よね and じゃん and I still find it confusing, feeling iffy about choosing one over the other.

> めっちゃ褒めてくれるじゃん

[@aguijonazo mentioned](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/94524/%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E5%84%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%AD-%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E5%84%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%82%E3%81%92%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%AD-%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E5%84%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%AD?noredirect=1#comment154128_94524) よね suggests the speaker assumes the listen holds a similar opinion. But how do I understand

> めっちゃ褒めてくれるよね

Does this sound too strong, because it doesn't seem to be used a lot? What other 語尾 can go there? でしょ? だろう? What else?

> めっちゃ褒めてくれてるじゃん

Also this doesn't occur often either, is it idiomatic?

Comment: Did you have any particular reason for using these examples instead of those in your previous question? What kind of situation do you have in mind? It seems hard to imagine one in which these are interpreted as accusations. Then what do you mean by “strong”?

Comment: @aguijonazo Oh I got a sense that よね, じょん, and other 語尾 seem to have different shades of meaning with different locutions, so maybe I should try and understand them on a case-by-case basis? This line is just something I remembered using and pondering over a while ago, and I thought it seemed like a different question with this line. As for "strong", I just had in mind a very partial and probably inaccurate idea that よね sometimes carries an accusatory tone, but I don't think it's necessarily the case here in this line. Still, I wonder if よね makes it sound (ever so slightly) unfriendly.

Comment: I have the feeling it depends much on the surrounding sentences and it is worth noting that examples in dungarian's answer are followed by another phrase, which makes the sentences somehow more natural.

Comment: One thing is that じゃん sounds more 馴れ馴れしい, which may  make it inappropriate to use e.g. among office colleagues.

Comment: FYI: [日本語の語尾「よね」の使い方](http://headjockaa.g1.xrea.com/realjp/yone.html) and [関西方言のヤンナとヨナ](https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/12296/19-01.pdf), though neither answers your question directly.

Answer (score 2):

How to parse and interpret them, is determined by so may surrounding elements.

Just to prove a point, here's a *bad example*. I wish I could've come up with a better one:

> So I went to the zoo yesterday, **right?** And the Japanese were excited about a loaf of bread.

I used the word "right". Immense effort will be required to explain when/why to use one over the other, from the following possible "synonyms":

- I went to the zoo yesterday, **eh?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **u dig?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **okay?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **you see?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **alright?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **get it?**
- I went to the zoo yesterday, **namsayin**

WhatI'msayin is, I am able to pick the appropriate one because of experience. I would choose one when arguing with my homies in the hood, but another when negotiating with my boss in the office.

---

褒めて**くれてる** and 褒めて**くれる** deliver a different message, so I'll just stick with 褒めて**くれてる** to generate these examples:

- A1. あなた今日めっちゃ褒めてくれてる**じゃん**。ありがとね
- A2. あなた今日めっちゃ褒めてくれてる**よね**。ありがとね
- B1. あの人私のことめっちゃ褒めてくれてる**じゃん**、だから私のこと好きなんだと思う
- B2. あの人私のことめっちゃ褒めてくれてる**よね**、だから私のこと好きなんだと思う
- C1. 私が駄目な女ってどういうこと？普段はめっちゃ褒めてくれてる**じゃん**
- C2. 私が駄目な女ってどういうこと？だってさ、普段はめっちゃ褒めてくれてる**よね**

I think the differences between 1 and 2 for each examples are trivial enough to be considered subjective. It also depends on the region you are in, especially with じゃん. So you probably shouldn't take my following analysis seriously:

- A1 sounds straightforward happier
- A2 sounds calmer (thus ironically may sound happier than A1)
- B1 sounds confident that someone has a crush on her
- B2 may be asking for her friend to agree
- C1 sounds straightforward disagreeing
- C2 required additional "だってさ" to clarify there is disagreement
- じゃん **may be** considered a double negative ("isn't it?")
- よね is a rhetorical question ("you see?")
- I **don't** imagine posh people using じゃん
- I **do** imagine posh people using よね
- じゃん sounds childish and cute
- よね sounds feminine

---

While I don't think じゃん is **stronger** over よね in terms of the message, I agree with you for two reasons:

- じゃん has a 濁音
- Somehow for me it's easier to imagine someone hyped up choosing じゃん

---

You may even add "ね" at the end of じゃん:

- A. そんなの無理じゃん**ね**
- B. そんなの無理じゃん、**ね？**
- C. そんなの無理じゃん、**ねぇ？**

If you ask me, these three have subtle differences:

- A sounds like a dialect from the West
- B is laughing it off ("haha seriously what an idiot")
- C is rolling its eyes ("ugh, can't believe it")

---

> でしょ? だろう? What else?

- (褒めてくれる or 褒めてくれてる) + **じゃない？**
- (褒めてくれる or 褒めてくれてる) + **ことない？**
- and more

And each of them may be mutated:

- でございましょ？
- ではございませんか？
- ではござらぬか
- ジャマイカ

Furthermore there are dialects:

- じゃんね？
- やん？
- だら？
- べ？

And so many more... although not all of them are universally compatible with each other.

Following may work too:

- おたく今日めっちゃ褒めてくれてる**ざましょ**？
- あなた今日めっちゃ褒めてくれてる**っしょ**？

Comment: This answer is helpful. Thanks! +1 But it's actually the nuanced and trivial differences that I'm wondering about.

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference seems what knowledge **the speaker thinks** is shared by the listener. Roughly

- Xよね : the speaker may or may not assume the listener knows/agrees that X
- Xじゃん : the speaker assumes that the listener knows/agrees that X

---

By examples.  I will use (R) and (D) to indicate the rising tone (as in question) and the decreasing tone (as an afterthought, it does not matter much).

**EXAMPLE 1**

- 私去年アメリカ行ったじゃん？ (R or D) *You know, I went to the US last year*

Here アメリカ行ったよね? sounds odd. (R) or (D) sounds a question/confirmation about the speaker's own action and as such speaker sounds amnesiac.

**EXAMPLE 2**

- 私ここに眼鏡置いたよね?(R)

Here 置いたじゃん is odd. Using じゃん means the speaker thinks the listener knows she put her glasses here, in which case she does not have to ask in the first place.

**EXAMPLE 3**

(Assume the speaker and the listener are playing basketball and the former shot successfully three times in a row)

- 私天才じゃん(D)

Here using 天才だよね is a bit odd. It sounds like a sheer question/confirmation. The じゃん version is natural based on the fact that the lister watched how good the speaker was.

**EXAMPLE 4**

This is not directly relevant to the question, but there is a 'blaming' usage (which I guess made you think these constructions sound sometimes 'strong').

- 早く宿題終わらせなさいっていったよね？

This is naturally used by a mother scolding a boy who is worried about finishing homework in the last week of summer vacation. Using じゃん does not sound right. I guess it can be understood じゃん's 'friendliness', but if following the principle as above, the mother thinks the current situation is not consistent with the child's knowing he must finish homework asap, in other words, knowing that and not doing it is idiotic. (Hence 'strong').

On the other hand

- 明日雨降るよって言ったじゃん/いったよね？

Here じゃん is better, but both are possible e.g. by a wife to a husband who came home soaked in a shower, referring to the conversation last night. Using よね implies the strong accusation as above, so not appropirate.

---

Turning to the sentences in question, I assume it is saying *You praise a lot*.

- 褒めてくれるじゃん indicates that the speaker considers the fact that the listener praises a lot as obvious or at least as something felt by the listener as well. In other words, the listener praises in the way that her praising is rather noticeable by everybody.
- 褒めてくれるよね does not assume that the listener is aware of her praising a lot herself. It can sound like *You praise a lot, although it may be nothing you are doing consciously*. That said, it can be used in the じゃん situation above as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think some more specific context is needed to discuss finer nuances - who is praising whom? I can see at least two possible contexts: 1) The listener is prasing the speaker. 2) Someone else is praising the speaker and the listener.

I quickly skimmed [the last question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/94524/%e8%aa%b0%e3%81%ab%e3%82%82%e5%84%aa%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad-%e8%aa%b0%e3%81%ab%e3%82%82%e5%84%aa%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%82%e3%81%92%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad-%e8%aa%b0%e3%81%ab%e3%82%82%e5%84%aa%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad) and it seems that the first context applies here.

With that context in mind, I would say that the -よね version somewhat implies that the speaker has had the same opinion (that the listener praises the speaker) for a while. The -じゃん version doesn't have such implication, at least not as strongly - the speaker might have just noticed that. It's not a hard division but I think there is such a tendency.

On a related note, the third version ending with -くれてるじゃん suggests that the 褒める event has just happened, and it is probably a new development.

I don't see any difference in idiomaticity among the three versions - they are all natural. I don't know how you know "this doesn't occur often", but I think idiomaticity and frequency are separate, although they can correlate.